# Lower triangular matrix similar to an upper triangular one

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true that any lower triangular square matrix on a field, is similar to an upper triangular matrix? (So defining a triangular linear tranformation is simpler).

Comment: Well, since any square matrix is similar to its transpose the answer is yes.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is true. Just use similarity matrix

$$S = \begin{bmatrix} & & & 1 \\ & & 1 & \\ & \mathinner{\mkern1mu\raise1pt\hbox{.}\mkern2mu\raise4pt\hbox{.}} & & \\ 1 & & & \end{bmatrix}.$$